# accordion is not working in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load ajax response on button click the response come properly and I am appending these response properly where I want but the only problem is that for response part accordion is not working. Here is my response:

```
<div class="articles-content title">here is some title</div>
    <div class="articles-content content exam-details">
         <p style="text-align: justify;">
              <span style="font-size:14px;">
                  <span style="font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">here some content</span>
              </span>
         </p>
    </div>
```

I am putting response in a foreach loop after span:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="someid">
    <div class="ui accordion">
        <?php
        foreach($somevariable as $var)
        { ?>
            <div class="some class">some title</div>
            <div class="someclass">some content</div> 
            <span class="ca_eng"><?php $x;?></span>
        <?php $x++;
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#readmore').click(function(){
            var limit = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "here is my url",
                    type:post,
                    data:{limit:limit},
                    sucess:function(result)
                    {
                        $limit1 = parseInt(limit)+10;
                        $('#readmore').val(limit);
                        $('.ca_eng').after(result);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

response append after `<span class="ca_eng"></span>` successfully but for response part accordion not working.

I've tried `append()` function in success but it is not working, I also tried below code in success of ajax method:

```
$('.ui accordion').accordion();
```

I also tried this like:

```
$('.ui accordion').accordion({
    active:false,
    collapsible:true
});
```

but no luck please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the accordion first and append the result like

```
$.ajax({
          url: "here is my url",
          type:post,
          data:{limit:limit},
          sucess:function(result)
          {
              $(result).find('.ui accordion').accordion();
              $limit1 = parseInt(limit)+10;
              $('#readmore').val(limit);
              $('.ca_eng').append(result);
          }
 });
```

Or even you can try like

```
sucess:function(result)
          {
              $limit1 = parseInt(limit)+10;
              $('#readmore').val(limit);
              $('.ca_eng').append(result);
              $('.ca_eng').find('.ui accordion').accordion();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 $('.ui accordion').accordion("refresh");  in success
```

[refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh)